# Opencv Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

I recorded a video to test out the cascade classifier. I wrote a script as follow to record how many times the cascade classifier recognize my face in the short video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./data/cascade.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/jianyepa/opencv-learning/output.avi')
count = 0

print cap.isOpened()
while 1:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                roi_color = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                count += 1
                print 'face detected'

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

print count
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Somehow, if I play the video to end, it will show the following output

> True
>
> face detected
>
> face detected
>
> face detected
>
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor,
>   file /home/jianyepa/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line
>   7456 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cascade.py", line 11,
>   in 
>       gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error: /home/jianyepa/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7456: error:
>   (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor

However, if I terminate the video before it end, the output is like expected

> True
>
> face detected
>
> face detected
>
> 2

Can someone give some idea on what is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: After `ret, frame = cap.read()`, check if `frame is not None`

Comment: @ZdaR Sorry, i cant get you, is it add `if frame is not None:` then `continue` ?

Comment: It depends on you what you want to do if frame is none, you may `continue`, `print "Frame empty"` or maintain a counter of empty frames, etc. But it is very unlikely that you may get empty frame in middle of stream.

Comment: @ZdaR checked, the frame is not empty. But error still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are trying to perform operations on a frame that is not even available.

Just make this change-

```
while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)

                for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                        roi_color = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                        count += 1
                        print 'face detected'

                cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
        else: break

print count
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, but I not understand what is the purpose of adding `if ret` and what is it did so the script reading correct frame?

Comment: In your code, the while loop continues even when the video is over. ret is just a flag to know if the frame is read properly or not. Then you can perform your operations